# Excel formula checklist in employees

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to know about this Excel formula and how it works

```
IFERROR(COUNTIF(OFFSET(T_E[[#Headers],[EMPLOYEE NAME]],MATCH(I_E,L_E,0),MATCH("ACT 1 DT",L_H,0)-1,1,N_S),">0")&" / "&N_S,"")
```

Please tell me about this formula and how can I change this by adding or removing.

Answer (score 0):

The best for trying how function works is to try it in excel, but still...
You want to know what the whole function works or just how partial functions work?
In general, the function addresses to formatted table and to named parts of the table, so it should return value from formatted table, that is x rows from employee name in row and x columns from employee name in this row.
How many depends on what is under "I_E", "L_E" and "L_H" and "N_S", I cannot tell without this knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to evaluate a formula

If you would like to better understand how a complex formula works, use the [Formula Evaluator](https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/excel_formula_evaluator.html) in Excel. Therefore select the cell that contains the formula, and on the *Formulas* tab, in the *Formula Auditing* group, click *Evaluate Formula*.

Also there is a [documentation for all formula functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188). With this and the *Formula Evaluator* you should be able to trace what the formula does.